# How to replace a blend's spine with a text outline in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text

I'm having a weird problem in Illustrator CC. I created a blend of objects. Usually, I can then manually create any path and can easily replace the blend's spine with that path.

But when I create a text object, convert it to outline, and attempt to use that as the blend's spine, the option `Replace Spine` is grey.

Why is this and how can I work around it?

[image]

Comment: I think a brush would be more effective in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem rests in the fact that your outlines are a group of paths as opposed to a single path. Ungroup and release their compound paths as much as they will, and try again.

The `Replace Spine` effect will only ever be available when you have a single path as the new spine selected. Illustrator won't know what to with two separate spines.

Comment: Wow, this helps! Thanks a lot. May I ask the next question. The method works fine on a single letter, on whole text it doesn't work even when everything ungroup and released. It seem to me, because more then one path selected... Any way to overcome it?

Comment: You *can't* use it on more than a single path at a time. You'll just have to use multiple copies of the blend.